# Call Object Method using ASM -- Part 2

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-2010, basm

This question is based on a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453238/call-object-method-using-asm), but that's just FYI.

I've managed to get it working, however, I've found something that's not clear to me, so if anyone can explain the following behaviour, it would be awesome.

I have the following class:

```
type
  TMyObj = class
  published
    procedure testex(const s: string; const i: integer);
  end;

procedure TMyObj.testex(const s: string; const i: integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(s + IntToStr(i));
end;
```

and the following two procedures:

```
procedure CallObjMethWorking(AMethod: TMethod; const AStrValue: string; const AIntValue: Integer);
begin
  asm
    PUSH DWORD PTR AIntValue;
    PUSH DWORD PTR AStrValue;
    CALL AMethod.Code;
  end;
end;

procedure CallObjMethNOTWorking(AInstance, ACode: Pointer; const AStrValue: string; const AIntValue: Integer);
begin
  asm
    MOV EAX, AInstance;
    PUSH DWORD PTR AIntValue;
    PUSH DWORD PTR AStrValue;
    CALL ACode;
  end;
end;
```

In order to test the working version, one needs to call the following:

```
procedure ...;
var
  LObj: TMyObj;
  LMethod: TMethod;
  LStrVal: string;
  LIntVal: Integer;
begin
  LObj := TMyObj.Create;
  try
    LMethod.Data := Pointer( LObj );
    LMethod.Code := LObj.MethodAddress('testex');

    LStrVal := 'The year is:' + sLineBreak;
    LIntVal := 2012;

    CallObjMethWorking(LMethod, LStrVal, LIntVal);
  finally
    LObj.Free;
  end; // tryf
end;
```

and in order to test the **NOT** working version:

```
procedure ...;
var
  LObj: TMyObj;
  LCode: Pointer;
  LData: Pointer;
  LStrVal: string;
  LIntVal: Integer;
begin
  LObj := TMyObj.Create;
  try
    LData := Pointer( LObj );
    LCode := LObj.MethodAddress('testex');

    LStrVal := 'The year is:' + sLineBreak;
    LIntVal := 2012;

    CallObjMethNOTWorking(LData, LCode, LStrVal, LIntVal);
  finally
    LObj.Free;
  end; // tryf
end;
```

And finally the question: why isn't **CallObjMethNOTWorking** working, while **CallObjMethWorking** is? I'm guessing that there's something special in how the compiler treats TMethod... but since my assembly knowledge is limited, I can't understand it.

I would highly appreciate if someone could explain this to me, thank you!

Comment: The 3 parameters are passed in registers. I don't know where the stack comes into play. Have you read the program control section of the delphi language guide?

Comment: @David, I just did, it seems that if I call PUSH EAX, MOV EDX, DWORD PTR AStrValue; MOV ECX, DWORD PTR AIntValue; CALL ACode; it works perfectly, except that it raises an exception(after execution)..., I get that the string is already passed by reference and the integer by value, but I still don't get it...

Comment: why are you pushing EAX? And why do you need to use asm to call a method?

Comment: aaa... I see, so if I push EAX, EDX, ECX the do the MOVE into EDX, ECX, make the CALL and then POP EAX, EDX, ECX no exception and it works, but why can't I use PUSH DWORD PTR for AStrValue and AIntValue?

Comment: The parameters are passed in registers! What is the stack being used for?

Comment: @Daivd errr, let's just say that I'm trying to use something that I don't fully understand, from what I know, only the first 3 params. are passed into registers, if a procedure/function has more than 3, the N-3 parameters will be passed on to the stack, in case of the method, the first parameter(if I understand correctly) is Self, so if a method has 3 parameters, the last one will be passed on to the stack, do I understand correctly?

Comment: You method has three parameters, including the implicit self parameter

Comment: in this case, yes, but it was an "extended" question to help me understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default calling convention in Delphi Win32 is "register". The first parameter is passed in EAX, the second in EDX and the third in ECX. The stack is only used if there are more than three parameters, or if value types larger than 4 bytes are passed, but that is not the case in your example.

Your first CallObjMethWorking procedure works because the compiler has **already** placed aStrValue in EDX and aIntValue in ECX when CallObjMethWorking was called. However, since you are not cleaning up your two push instructions, bad things are bound to happen when the procedure returns.

Your code should look like this. The stdcall directive is optional in this case, but it might be a good idea to use it for things like this to make sure your parameters aren't lost because you use the registers for other purposes before you get around to actually call the method:

```
procedure CallObjMeth(AInstance, ACode: Pointer; const AStrValue: string; const AIntValue: Integer); stdcall;
asm
  MOV EAX, AInstance;
  MOV EDX, DWORD PTR AStrValue;
  MOV ECX DWORD PTR AIntValue;
  CALL ACode;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Henrick, just tested and you're correct, can you please be more specific about "cleaning push instructions"?

Comment: In most cases each PUSH instruction has to be matched by a POP instruction. There are a few exceptions, such as when calling methods with a calling convention that leaves it to the callee to clean up the stack, but this wasn't one of them.

Comment: BTW, the parameters were moved to wrong registers in my original answer. Fixed it just now.

Answer (score 6):

Henrick Hellström is correct with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455103/69588), and I notice that your question is tagged with Delphi 2010 and thus only concerns Win32. However, you might be interested to see what the situation would look like if you move forward to Win64 (Delphi >= XE2), so I added an example Win64 version to Henrick's code:

```
procedure CallObjMeth(AInstance, ACode: Pointer; const AStrValue: string; const AIntValue: Integer); stdcall;
asm
{$IFDEF CPU386}
  MOV EAX, AInstance;
  MOV EDX, DWORD PTR AStrValue;
  MOV ECX, DWORD PTR AIntValue;
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
   //On MacOSX32 ESP = #######Ch here       
   SUB ESP, 0Ch  
  {$ENDIF}     
  CALL ACode;
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
   ADD ESP, 0Ch // restoring stack
  {$ENDIF}     
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF CPUX64}{$IFDEF WIN64} // <- see comments
  .NOFRAME //Disable stack frame generation
  //MOV RCX, AInstance {RCX} //<- not necessary because AInstance already is in RCX
  MOV R10, ACode {RDX}
  MOV RDX, AStrValue {R8}
  MOV R8D, AIntValue {R9D}
  SUB RSP, 28h    //Set up stack shadow space and align stack: 4*8 bytes for 4 params + 8 bytes bytes for alignment
  {$IFNDEF DO_NOT_TEST_STACK_ALIGNMENT}
  MOVDQA XMM5, [RSP]  //Ensure that RSP is aligned to DQWORD boundary -> exception otherwise
  {$ENDIF}
  CALL R10 //ACode
  ADD RSP, 28h  //Restore stack
{$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
end;
```

*There are several explanatory notes to make:*

**1) `ASM` statement**: In Delphi XE2 x64 there is no mixing of pascal and asm code, so the only way to write assembly code is in a routine that is comprised of a single `asm..end`  block, no `begin..end`. Note that the `begin..end` around your 32-bit asm code also does have an effect. Specifically, you are forcing the generation of a stack frame and let the compiler make local copies of the function parameters. (If you resort to using assembly in the first place, you would might not want the compiler to do that.)

**2) Calling convention**:
On Win64, there is only a single calling convention. Things like `register` and `stdcall` are effectively meaningless; it is all the same, [Microsoft's Win64 calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx). It is essentially this: parameters are passed in `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8` and `R9` registers (and/or `XMM0-XMM4`, return values in `RAX/XMM0`. Larger than 64-bit values are passed via reference.

Called functions may use: `RAX, RCX, RDX, R8-R11, ST(0)-ST(7), XMM0-XMM5, YMM0-YMM5, YMM6H-YMM15H`, and must preserve `RBX, RSI, RDI, RBP, R12-R15, XMM6-XMM15`. Where appropriate, called functions need to issue `CLD`/`EMMS`/`VZEROUPPER` instructions to restore the CPU to the expected state.

**3) Alignment and shadow space**
Importantly, each function has its own shadow space on the stack, which is at least 4 QWORD param's worth of stack space, even if there are no params and irrespective of whether the called function actually touches it. Moreover, at the site of each function call (at each `CALL` statement), `RSP` is expected to be 16-byte aligned (same for `ESP` on MacOSX32, btw.). 
This often leads to things like: `sub rsp, ##; call $$; add rsp, ##` constructs in which ## would be the sum of the (QWORD) parameters with which the function is to be called, plus an optional 8 bytes for alignment of `RSP`. Note that the alignment of `RSP` at the `CALL` site results in `RSP = ###8h` upon function entry (because `CALL` puts the return address on the stack), so assuming nobody messes with `RSP` before you do, you can expect it to be that.

In the example provided, the SSE2 `MOVDQA` instruction is used to test the alignment of `RSP`. (`XMM5` is used as destination register because it can be freely modified yet cannot contain any function parameter data).

**4) Assumptions**
The code here assumes that the compiler does not insert code to change `RSP`. There may be situations in which this may not be true, so beware of making this assumption.

**5) Exception handling** Exception handling in Win64 is a bit complicated and should properly be done by the compiler (the example code above does not do this). To allow the compiler to do so, ideally your code should use the new BASM directives/pseudo-instructions `.PARAMS`, `.PUSHNV` and `.SAVENV` as outlined by [Allen Bauer here](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2011/10/10/38940). Given the right (wrong) situation, bad things could happen otherwise.

Comment: +1 thank you for your very deep explanation, just one more question, on x86 we have to move aInstance to EAX, however on x64(RCX = EAX(?)) AInstance is already in RCX because it's the first parameter?

Comment: @Dorin - yes, the reason that it is in RCX is that it is the first parameter

Comment: Be careful with {$IFDEF CPUX64} in asm. The Win64 calling convention is not the same as the Linux x64 or OSX x64 calling conventions. It's safer to use {$IFDEF WIN64} instead.

Comment: @HenrickHellström - you're probably right, I'll change that to WIN64 to be on the safe side. However, since Delphi doesn't yet support those other platforms, there's no way of knowing with certainty what they'll use as Delphi's default calling convention there.

Comment: @Henrick - there's another problem with the WIN... defines: later Win OSes might support multiple CPU architectures. I therefore added the WIN64 ifdef rather than replaced the CPUX64 one for now.

Comment: @PhiS: Just two more things to make your answer complete (great post btw): Firstly, if the code is compiled against a target you haven't implemented support for, the procedure will have an empty body and the compiler will not emit any warning or error. Secondly, could you add a few words about using .NOFRAME as opposed to omitting it and also omitting the instructions that align the stack before making leaf calls?